# creating fragments inside popup window

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying create a popup windows which shows a list of emoticons. Same As in following image.
[image]
For that I've created a layout with viewpager. For each view I'm trying to create fragment. Can anyone please suggest me how to implement fragment inside popup window. I'm new to android. Thanks.

Comment: Post the code which you have tried.

Comment: Have you figured this out?